# Where do raid items go if your Inventory is full?

Tags: destiny

I'm getting to the point where I'm running out of inventory room for my favorite Exotic and Legendary weapons.  I know that when you miss a rare or better engram drop in an activity they show up in the Post Office to pick up latter.

**Does this also hold true for mission rewards, chest loot, and raid boss drops?**

Not just for engrams, but named items like the raid armors and weapons as well?  I need to know if I need to vault items when I run the raid to make sure I have the available inventory space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about raids from personal expedrience but I know that end of mission rewards from other things (eg story and strikes) can have things sent to you by post office. I would assume it is the same for raid rewards and  Link of Origin has confirmed it in comments.

My opinion would be to always make room to be on the safe side anyway.

Comment: Saw this happen to someone today from crucible rewards. They got a shader they had no room for and it was in the post office later.

Comment: This answer is correct. If your inventory is full at the time of receiving an item, the friendly postmaster holds on to it for you at the tower, raid gear included. I have seen this happen to someone before, so don't worry, it won't disappear into the void ;)